# Windows 10 PC is getting worst day by day

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am using Windows 10 now. The problem I am facing is that the amount of empty RAM is decreasing day by day. I installed Windows 10 about 1 month ago. Then after installing all the necessary software, at that time the RAM was about 55 percent empty. But now RAM is empty about 35 percent. I have not installed any new software. Now my computer seems slower than before.

What should I do now? Should I reinstall Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be due to various software updates. In addition, many updates come to Windows, which often slows down performance.
If you do not have an **SSD** Drive on your PC, then adding an SSD Drive will get a lot of fast performance. You can also increase your RAM.

Comment: I will add a SSD drive and an extra RAM Kit to boost the performance of my PC.

Answer (score 3):

> I am using Windows 10 now. ... I installed Windows 10 about 1 month
> ago.

1. Fresh Install or upgrade from another OS like Windows 7. This is important information.
2. How much memory?  Windows 10 64-bit base memory usage is 4 GB and then up and down from there. It will idle at 4 - 5 GB used.

You need at least 8 GB today for Windows 10 64-bit to run smoothly.

3. Drivers:  Most people forget this. Update BIOS, Chipset and all other drivers. Use the manufacturer's Driver Update app for this.
4. Windows Updates:  Make sure Windows 10 is fully up to date.
5. Legacy software:  Make sure you are using modern versions of software.
6. Disks:  I have an SSD drive in this computer and a 7200-rpm drive in the mate beside me. The SSD certainly starts faster but the HDD machine (ThinkPad X230) works great.
7. Should you reinstall Windows?

(a) If this was an upgrade, then yes as upgrades sometimes do not work well.

(b) If not an upgrade, try the ideas above, but it may still be a good idea to start fresh, update Drivers and see how it works.

Once 7 (b) is done, make sure you are installing modern versions of software. Check overall operation before installing anything.

This computer of mine here has been running Windows 10 Pro 64-bit since October 2016.

Answer (score 1):

You should look in `Task Manager` to figure out which specific programs are utilizing your RAM. You can end those specific tasks to free up RAM. You can also disable them from the `Startup` tab to prevent them from starting back up when rebooting.

Comment: I will look up ```Task Manager```. Thank you sir your valuable advice.